# How can I acces variable from another class I Java

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft

I made minecraft plugin which have afk function but I need when player left and is in AFK list remove them! So I made this

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();

// Im getting the table like this

instance.MyTable
```

Which dont works because I have already and quit event that just set custom quit messsage so it is weird

So my code looks like this!

```
public class QuitEvent implements Listener{
    
    afkCommand instance = new afkCommand();
    
    @EventHandler
    public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event) {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        
        event.setQuitMessage("");
        Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.WHITE + "[" + ChatColor.RED + "-" + ChatColor.WHITE + "] " + ChatColor.YELLOW + player.getDisplayName() + " has disconnected!");
        if (instance.AFK_Players.contains(event.getPlayer().getDisplayName())) {
            instance.AFK_Players.remove(event.getPlayer().getDisplayName());
            Bukkit.getConsoleSender().sendMessage("[Pixeluted Surival] " + event.getPlayer().getDisplayName() + " has been removed from AFK list because of quit!");
        }
    }
}
```

Also please correct me if Im wrong using this forum Im new to here!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well i don't know what your `MyClass` looks like or your `MyTable`. Judging off of first glance,First you need to add event handler within your constuctor to each object or item using it by creating an instance of listener eg

```js
QuitEvent handler = new QuitEvent();
object.addListener(handler);
```

Then add the first code snippet you sent in your main class method. Plus i don't know if you are implementing `actionlistener` or `listener` but which ever the case make sure to import the classes you are implementing into your constructor class.

Comment: Well Im registering all listener and events but the problem is that the table im getting from another class is seem to be nil or even in the table is nothing but in real there is some list of players!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting the variable to static and used diffrent type of accesing it!
Thanks for all responds!